# ReactJS handling a lot of data in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a React application that needs to handle a lot of data. Overall it's a simple application :

- Header with a few links
- Search bar
- Table

The catch is, depending on what is being searched for...the table needs to display up to 1,000 rows by about 100 columns. When the http request returns this data and set in state, the application pretty much becomes unusable. Any other attempt to update state after it contains that data either takes forever or crashes the browser. Even when I limit the table to display 20 rows x 100 columns, the state update is significantly faster, but still noticeable to update.

I tried scouring the web to find a good solution and have come up short so any ideas/help/suggestions are welcome. If redux will help, I have no issue implementing that, I just don't want to waste my time if there is no payoff.

Comment: I appears the rendering is the slowdown. I haven't used it myself but https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List has consistent performance at a 1000 rows +. The example has only a minimal amount of columns. But, just like they compute the visible rows and only render them, you could also compute the visible columns and only render them.

Comment: So I'm currently using https://react-table.js.org/#/story/100k-rows-w-pivoting-sub-components for the table. The table itself is rendering fine, however if I try to type in the search bar (which updates the state onChange) after the data is in the state/dom, it takes forever for the input to change (state update)

Comment: Can you add some code for the component? Particularly showing the render() and the network call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably re-rendering the entire table along with the search bar whenever you type in it.  Maybe try putting the table into a subcomponent which implements `shouldComponentUpdate()`.  Is the table data supposed to dynamically update whenever you type a character into the input?  That might be expensive, you could also consider only re-rendering the table when a user clicks the "search" button by the input.

Rather than beat around the bush trying to figure out if it's a rendering issue, though, I recommend using the [React performance tools](https://reactjs.org/docs/perf.html)*.  Benchling has [a solid blog post](https://benchling.engineering/performance-engineering-with-react-e03013e53285) which walks through the process of performance debugging in React, but the magic is `Perf.printWasted()`.  It will show you how much time was spent re-rendering components which were the same after the rendering (e.g. your table when you're only changing the text input).  Test steps:

1. From the console, run: `Perf.start()`
2. type in your input, ideally just one keystroke
3. console : `Perf.stop()`
4. console : `Perf.printWasted()`

This method is super painless, but you can also [use the Chrome profiling tools](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#profiling-components-with-the-chrome-performance-tab) to find out the same info.

*I just found out that they've been deprecated in hot-off-the-press React 16, but you're likely still using a 15.x variant which works fine.

Also, +1 for react-virtualized!  It's excellent, supports many columns and layouts.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly your problem is not the amount of data - problem in DOM rendering.

I think the best solution for you will be to render only visible part of table. For example try to use [this library](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) or similar.

Comment: So I'm currently using https://react-table.js.org/#/story/100k-rows-w-pivoting-sub-components for the table. The table itself is rendering fine, however if I try to type in the search bar (which updates the state onChange) after the data is in the state/dom, it takes forever for the input to change (state update)

Comment: I'm not sure but this issue https://github.com/react-tools/react-table/issues/403 has example how to use `react-table` with `AutoSizer` component from `react-virtualized`.